# Do temporary entities give experience upon expiring?

Tags: dota-2

All creeps, heroes, summons, as well as most illusions give experience if killed in the vicinity of enemy heroes. Many of these entities are temporary and will also disappear if a timer runs out. Do nearby enemies get experience in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No experience is granted for entities expiring.